# Bootstrap modal with a form not showing properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I made a modal which includes a form asking for information about a book. After clicking the button Add Book the modal is supposed to show so that one can enter the information about the book and after clicking add the entered data is used to create a Bootstrap card element and append it to the page. The problem is when clicking the Add Book button the modal shows but it isn't displaying properly (it appears fragmented with the Title and inputs floating above the page contents).

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add-book-modal">AddBook</button>
        <div class="modal fade" id="add-book-modal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="add-book-modal" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title">Add a new book</h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form id="add-form">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="title" class="col-form-label">Title:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="author" class="col-form-label">Author:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="author" name="author">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="comment" class="col-form-label">Comments:</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" id="comment" name="comment"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="add">Add</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/MihajloRashajkovski/3qg082p5/1/

Comment: Copy and paste the example from the bootstrap page. So you can see if you have a mistake

Answer (score 0):

Is seems strange for me that div with class="modal fade" is inside button type="button". Move it inside container div class="container".